# pass variable in Gradle to bash file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, shell, android-studio, gradle

I have an android project.

I need to run Shell after the project build and create an APK file.

I Create installSystem.sh.

I use external tools in Android Studio.

In Gradle, I have 4 variables And need to pass there to shell arguments.

```
ext {
    // Version
    versionMajor = 1
    versionMinor = 0
    versionPatch = 0
    versionBuild = 0
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image: e]
[image]